# Can't figure out a method to do this. Python, csv, pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Ok, so I'm working on a backtest for stock data and here is where I am stumped:

I have 150 csv files, each one contains daily stock data for the length of the stock's life. Each stock has a different starting date.

```
Date        Close       etc
2015-05-05   123.24
```

I want to check certain conditions on certain days. So, for example, on 2015-05-05, what was the closing price of every stock in the 150 files? Then take some action, then check 2015-05-06, etc. How can I make a row by row conditional statement with all these csv files?:

```
if date in csv_file:
    return row in csv_file that has this date
```

Really not sure how to approach this, I know how to do it by hand, but that would day forever and that is what computers are for. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

150 files containing inception to date daily prices (OHLC, volume, etc) really isn't that much data.

I would read all of the csv files and put them into a single DataFrame indexed on date and symbol (assuming the symbols are unique across all csv files).  Once the data is in this flat format, you can rearrange it to your heart's content.

Comment: That would be like 100mb file with 1 million rows, there must be a better way.

Comment: Like I said, it's really not that much data.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexender is right, this isn't a lot of data, and it's probably easiest to read all the files into a single `DataFrame`, but when you get to the point where your data doesn't fit into memory, you can use [`dask`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) to operate on the data as if it were read into a `DataFrame` in memory. One nice feature is that it lets you pass a glob to `read_csv()` so you can operate on multiple csv files at once.

Using this approach, your code would look something like the following.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.read_csv('/path/to/csvs/fname*glob.csv')
ddf[ddf.Date == some_date].compute()
```

One small drawback of `dask` is that it is not as good at inferring types as `pandas` is so you may have to pass an explicit `dtype` to `read_csv()`.